# is it possible to set default value using annotations in gson?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

is it possible using annotation set default value to Gson properties? 
i want to use this default values after deSerialize/serialize

```
@SerializedName(key = "a", defaultValue = "hi")
public String a;

@SerializedName("b")
public String b;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default value in your setter method if the variable is null

```
@SerializedName("yourVariable")
public String yourVariable;

public String getYourVariable(){
    if(yourVariable==null){
       return defaultValue;
    }
    return yourVariable;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i want to use annotation